# Prove a certain equation

Tags: summation, factorial, gamma-function

Can anyone prove this equation? $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left( \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} \right)^3 = \left( \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{9}{8}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)} \right)^2$$ This is a closed-form sum by Ramanujan.

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html

According to the above website, G.H. Hardy gives a generalization of this sum.

If anyone can help proving this, I would really be grateful.

Comment: it let me see (and then download) Hardy's Twelve Lectures on Ramanujan. https://archive.org/details/pli.kerala.rare.37877/page/n21/mode/2up  You want the chapter on hypergeometric functions, the chapter begins on book page 101.

Answer (score 0):

beginning page of the chapter. See  full scan at [TWELVE](https://archive.org/details/pli.kerala.rare.37877/page/n21/mode/2up)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$a_n=\frac{(2 n-1)\text{!!}}{(2 n)\text{!!}}=\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \,\,\Gamma (n+1)}$$ which explains the appearance of hypergeometric functions.

$$S_k(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\, a_n^k\,x^n$$ produces

$$S_1(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}$$
$$S_2(x)=\frac{2 K(-x)}{\pi }$$
$$S_3(x)=\frac{4 K\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{x+1}\right)\right)^2}{\pi ^2}$$
$$S_4(x)=\, _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1,1,1;-x\right)$$
$$S_5(x)=\,
   _5F_4\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1,1,1,1; -x\right)$$ I am sure that you see the pattern.

Using $x=1$
$$S_3(1)=\left(\frac{2 K\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)\right)}{\pi }   \right)^2=\left( \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{9}{8}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{4}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)} \right)^2$$